About directional complements in 把 structure
I was wondering about the 把 structure when used with directional complements:
When we use directional complements with a place, we need to put the place between the complements, right? So for example we say "下课了，同学们一个个都走[出]教室[去]".
I also know we can use the 把 structure with directional complements, like "麻烦你把车子开[出来]".
I wanted to know if it's correct and if it sounds "natural" to say: "麻烦你把车子开[出]车库[来]", or if we usually don't use the 把 structure to say this :)
Thanks in advance!!!

Sounds natural to me!

Your sentence is acceptable, but the native may say:

麻烦你把车子开出来 or 麻烦你把车子從车库开出来

麻烦你把车子开进去 or 麻烦你把车子开到/进车库去


